# How do I make a php that links to css file work when included in a nested php

Tags: php, css

Here's the structure I'm working with:

```
www/
   includes/nav.php
   css/main.css
   css/mobile.css
   css/nav.css
   policies/1000/index.php
```

The index.php in the 1000 directory is able to include the nav.php file just fine. The nav.php file contains the link to the stylesheets, and all of the php files in the root directory are able to access the css files fine:

```
<link href="/css/nav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

However, the css is not showing up in policies/1000/index.php and I think it's because the nav.php file is trying to locate the css files in policies/1000/css/. How do I remedy this?

Comment: you need to use absolute url :| because nav.php can be loaded from many path :|

Comment: is your www directory server as a root directory? How do you access the file in the browser?

Comment: How do you include `nav.php` into `index.php`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are including `nav.php` in many files, you may use your site's url, so, in `nav.php`:

```
<link href="http://domain.com/css/your_file.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

NOTE: HTML's default stylesheet type is `text/css`, no need to add that attribute.